# WorksheetFunction.CountA returns different results when used on the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, windows-10

I need to load some data from Excel into Access and perform a lot of validation along the way. In order to know how many rows I should process I use the `CountA` function, then I skip the empty rows in column `A` and count the processed ones.

```vb
NonEmptyRowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyWorksheet.Range("A:A"))
```

This works most of the time pretty well. However, sometimes `CountA` returns `1,048,576` which is the max number of rows. I experience this problem on the same worksheet that I use for testing.

What would be the most reliable way to solve it? Do you know how to fix `CountA` or any alternative method?

I also have noticed that this happens when I don't close Excel properly in my macro like when I break the excecution during debugging. Might this be the case?

```vb
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
```

Then I have one more question: can I reuse an existing instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use globals from external applications opened through COM!

`WorksheetFunction` is a global object. When using it from Excel, it calls a worksheet function using the currently open application object.

When using it from Access, it calls the worksheet function using some application object, probably the first Excel application object opened. Which might not be the one you're currently using. So always be explicit on *which* application object you want to call it.

```
xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MyWorksheet.Range("A:A"))
```

Also note, when using late binding, this is the only way to call worksheet functions, so using it this way makes switching to late binding easier, which you often want to do, to make the application work with multiple versions of Office without needing to tweak references.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could call it like this too! I've just killed my code two times and with this fix it returns the correct number every time even though there are two abandoned excel instances from previous runs :-)